# How to enumerate horizontally instead of vertically in MCEXAM package using "tasks" package?

Tags: multicol, exam, tasks, mcexam

how do I use tasks package to put options as

a  b

c  d

Multicols puts the options as

a  c

b  d

See screenshot.[image]

here is the mwe

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% mcexams options.
\usepackage[output=concept
           ,numberofversions=2
           ,version=1
           ,seed=1
           ,randomizequestions=true
           ,randomizeanswers=false
           ,writeRfile=false
           ]{mcexam}

\usepackage{calc}
\renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\labelwidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BEGIN EXAM QUESTIONS %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{mcquestions}

\question Example 1 using multicol  Which of the following numbers is prime? This shows how \texttt{multicol} can be used to format options all on one line.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
    \answer 12
    \answer 16
    \answer[correct] 17
    \answer 20
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{multicols}

\question No package Example 2 Which of the following numbers is prime? This shows how \texttt{multicol} can be used to format options all on one line.
\begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
\answer 12
\answer 16
\answer[correct] 17
\answer 20
\end{mcanswerslist}


\question Example 3 If $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$  represent respectively the kinetic energies of an electron, an alpha particle and a proton each having same de Broglie wavelength than
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer[correct]{ (a*)  $ E_1 > E_3 > E_2 $}
\answer{ (b) $ E_2 > E_3 > E_1 $ }
\answer{ (c) $ E_1 > E_2 > E_3 $ }
\answer{ (d)  $ E_1 = E_3 = E_2 $}
\end{mcanswerslist}


\end{mcquestions}

 
\end{document}
```

Just fyi this is very similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595805/using-multicols-or-tasks-to-enumerate-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-in-auto)
I am unable to figure out the syntax.

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use the syntax `\begin{tasks}[options]{2}`\task … \end{tasks}`.

Comment: i tried a couple of variations. it didnt work. can you modify example 3 and show me how to write it?

Comment: I've posted an example with `tasks`. However, the `[correct]` optional argument was not replaced by something equivalent with tasks. I think you probably will have to type it by hand (possibly with a macro)  *after* the tasks environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% mcexams options.
\usepackage[output=concept
           ,numberofversions=2
           ,version=1
           ,seed=1
           ,randomizequestions=true
           ,randomizeanswers=false
           ,writeRfile=false
           ]{mcexam}

\usepackage{calc}
\renewenvironment{setmcquestion}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\labelwidth}}{\end{minipage}\par}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BEGIN EXAM QUESTIONS %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{mcquestions}

\question Example 1 using multicol Which of the following numbers is prime? This shows how \texttt{multicol} can be used to format options all on one line.

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
    \answer 12
    \answer 16
    \answer[correct] 17
    \answer 20
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{multicols}

\question No package Example 2 Which of the following numbers is prime? This shows how \texttt{multicol} can be used to format options all on one line.
\begin{mcanswerslist}[ordinal]
\answer 12
\answer 16
\answer[correct] 17
\answer 20
\end{mcanswerslist}

\question Example 3 If $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ represent respectively the kinetic energies of an electron, an alpha particle and a proton each having same de Broglie wavelength than
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer[correct]{ (a*) $ E_1 > E_3 > E_2 $}
\answer{ (b) $ E_2 > E_3 > E_1 $ }
\answer{ (c) $ E_1 > E_2 > E_3 $ }
\answer{ (d) $ E_1 = E_3 = E_2 $}
\end{mcanswerslist}

With tasks:
\begin{tasks}[label=(\alph*)](2)
\task\: (a*) $ E_1 > E_3 > E_2 $
\task\: (b) $ E_2 > E_3 > E_1 $
\task\: (c) $ E_1 > E_2 > E_3 $
\task\:(d) $ E_1 = E_3 = E_2 $
\end{tasks}

\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with this solution we are "displaying" the options the right way, but it wont be helpful as its not being considered as part of mcanswerslist environment. have to use tasks in such a way that options are within mcanswerslist, just like multicols.

Comment: @Aman: It must not be easy (if possible…) to patch `mcanswerslist` via tasks, as the former relies on `enumitem`.  Tasks uses a syntax similar to  enumitem, but is not a a part of the latter. What I would suggest would be to replace mcanswerslist with a customised version of tasks.