# How to properly align/indent questions (question text) and options in automultiplechoice?

Tags: exam, tasks, examdesign, auto-multiple-choice

How do i align the question and the option text properly such that the next line doesnt start from that far left but the indent/alignment is maintained as shown?

MWE Attached

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=4,layout=stacked]{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[box,completemulti,separateanswersheet,nopage,noshuffle]{automultiplechoice}    

\begin{document}



\AMCrandomseed{1237893}
\AMCboxStyle{shape=oval}
\def\AMCformQuestion#1{{\sc Q #1:}}
\def\AMCbeginQuestion#1#2{\par\noindent{\bf Q #1}#2\hspace*{1em}}    

\setdefaultgroupmode{withoutreplacement}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\element{general}{
\begin{question}{QuestionChemicalBondingStageA- 37 }
In nitrogen family, the \ce{H-X-H} bond angle in the hydrides gradually becomes closer to \ang{90} on going from \ce{N} to \ce{Sb}. This shows that gradually
\begin{choicescustom}
\begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
\task* \correctchoice{ The crystal lattice of ice is mostly formed by covalent as well as hydrogen bonds}
\task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases when heated from  \SI{0}{\celsius} to \SI{4}{\celsius}  due to the change in the structure of the cluster of water molecules}
\task* \correctchoice{ Above  \SI{4}{\celsius}  the thermal agitation of water molecules increases. Therefore, intermolecular  distance increase and water starts expanding}
\task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases from  \SI{0}{\celsius}  to a maximum at \SI{4}{\celsius}   because the entropy  (disorder) of the system increases}
\end{tasks}
\end{choicescustom}
\end{question}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\onecopy{1}{


\insertgroup{general}


\AMCcleardoublepage    

\AMCformBegin    

%%% beginning of the answer sheet header

\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \AMCform      
\end{multicols*}

}

\end{document}
```

Gives the following output which i would like to modify as shown.

[image]

the line starting with " 90º on going from " should be starting directly below " In nitrogen... " and not below "Q 1."

Exact same thing with options, like in option C I would like the text to start below the text and not below the option name.

Edit: Through some trial and error I found that indentation issue in answers/options is because of the tasks package. I still haven't been able to solve it using

```
\settasks{
item-indent = 2.5em
}
```

The indentation in question is still arising from AMC package.
Any head's up is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the `question` must be encapsulated in a `\parbox` to align its two (o more) lines.

The other settings take care of the rest.

The following code verifies that proper alignment is maintained when the `question` number has two digits.

[image: bx]

Tested with  `automultiplechoice.sty  2021/02/12 v1.5.0`  and
`automultiplechoice.sty  2018/12/29 v1.4.0`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[box,completemulti,separateanswersheet,nopage,noshuffle]{automultiplechoice}   

\RequirePackage{etex}
\usepackage[version=4,layout=stacked]{mhchem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{tikz} 
 \usepackage{showframe} %test margins

%%************************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AMCrep@perso[2]{\AMC@mem@answer{#1}\AMCanswer{#1}{\hspace*{0.5em}\parbox[c]{0.88\textwidth}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\buffspace}
\setlength{\buffspace}{3.2ex}
\newcommand{\setbuffspace}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1>9\relax
    \setlength{\buffspace}{1.9ex}%
    \else\setlength{\buffspace}{3.2ex}% 
    \fi
    \hspace*{\buffspace}%
}

\renewcommand{\AMCbeginQuestion}[2]{\noindent{\bf Q #1}\setbuffspace{\theAMCquestionaff}}
\setlength{\AMCinterBquest}{4ex}% % space inter questions <<<<<<<<<<

\settasks{% added <<<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=3.2em, % align with question  text
    before-skip = 0.5ex, %add space with the question,
    after-item-skip = 1.5ex plus 0.7ex minus 0.7ex, % item separation
}   
%%********************************************************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \AMCrandomseed{1237893}
    \AMCboxStyle{shape=oval}    
    
    \setdefaultgroupmode{withoutreplacement}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \element{general}{%
        \begin{question}{QuestionChemicalBondingStageA- 37 }% <<<<<<<<<< 
            \parbox[t]{0.9\textwidth}{In nitrogen family, the \ce{H-X-H} bond angle in the hydrides gradually becomes closer to \ang{90} on going from \ce{N} to \ce{Sb}. This shows that gradually}
            \begin{choicescustom}[]                 
                \begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The crystal lattice of ice is mostly formed by covalent as well as hydrogen bonds.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases when heated from  \SI{0}{\celsius} to \SI{4}{\celsius}  due to the change in the structure of the cluster of water molecules.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ Above  \SI{4}{\celsius}  the thermal agitation of water molecules increases. Therefore, intermolecular  distance increase and water starts expanding.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases from  \SI{0}{\celsius}  to a maximum at \SI{4}{\celsius}   because the entropy  (disorder) of the system increases.}
                \end{tasks}
            \end{choicescustom}
        \end{question}
        
        \setcounter{AMCquestionaff}{9} % test double digits alignment <<<<<         
        
        \begin{question}{QuestionChemicalBondingStageA- 37 }% <<<<<<<<<<<
            \parbox[t]{0.9\textwidth}{In nitrogen family, the \ce{H-X-H} bond angle in the hydrides gradually becomes closer to \ang{90} on going from \ce{N} to \ce{Sb}. This shows that gradually.}
            \begin{choicescustom}[]
                \begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The crystal lattice of ice is mostly formed by covalent as well as hydrogen bonds.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases when heated from  \SI{0}{\celsius} to \SI{4}{\celsius}  due to the change in the structure of the cluster of water molecules.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ Above  \SI{4}{\celsius}  the thermal agitation of water molecules increases. Therefore, intermolecular  distance increase and water starts expanding.}
                    \task* \correctchoice{ The density of water increases from  \SI{0}{\celsius}  to a maximum at \SI{4}{\celsius}   because the entropy  (disorder) of the system increases.}
                \end{tasks}
            \end{choicescustom}
        \end{question}
    }% end element
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    
    \onecopy{1}{%       
        \insertgroup{general}       
        \AMCcleardoublepage         
        \AMCformBegin      
         
        %%% beginning of the answer sheet header            
        \setlength{\AMCformVSpace}{5ex}
        
        \begin{multicols*}{2}
            \AMCform      
        \end{multicols*}            
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey @simon, thanks for your answer. this looks great. I will have to ask you for one more thing though. I want the option names ( A , B, C, or D) to begin right below the question text and not below the question number. ( see question image) and then the answer text after that. How do i do that?

Comment: Also it showed me some error "
`! Undefined control sequence.
\AMCrep@perso #1#2->\AMCmem@ireAJRep 
                                     {#1} \AMCanswer {#1}{\hspace *{1.65em}\...
l.105     }`
" . My amc version is "AMC version: 2020/03/30 v1.4.0+git2020-03-30" in case it helps. Here is the pdf i got when i copy-pasted your MWE. 

[link](https://imgur.com/undefined)

Comment: @Aman Sorry for my misunderstanding in the lineups. Please try the updated answer.  (Tested with the last two versions of AMC.)

Comment: Thank you Simon, for solving my issue!